# DSO -138 oscilloscope no detection of signal

Tags: current-measurement, oscilloscope, voltage-measurement, diy

As a project, I got myself a DIY oscilloscope to practice some soldering skills. As it turns out after I did all the hard work the display worked fine but my input voltage was nonexistent. To give more context to the device I was using, it is just about [like this one.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DJ1YS99)

I thought the internet would help me out a bit but the only video that even addressed the problem was [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tQGuCGl0GM). It was not very helpful, though, because it basically just said that I was likely the problem. That's not wrong but not helpful.

All in all, the display works fine, although some voltages are off, A+ and A- on the model being the pain culprits along with a few others. The manual briefly mentions fixing this problem and recommends "fixing" the problem (thanks) and going to a random forum that does not exist to my knowledge! I mean, the only problem is that the voltage reading is not there, just the X-Y graph.

If anyone can figure out why I am not getting a signal through the connector let me know, in the meantime I will go through the internet and see if anyone else has my problem. If I forgot any vital information for the experienced electrical engineers out there I will leave it in a edit bellow

[Manual for the scope.](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1427100/Diy-Dso-138.html)

For some reason that site does not have the schematic, so here it is:

[image]

V1 is not the correct voltage, should be 0 but is running at 3.3 volts, alongside V2, and AV- is running improperly at .8 Volts

Edit, I think I found the problem. For the life of me I forgot to check the values of the nonpolarised capacitors and probably goofed up somewhere. I will do an update if this works

Comment: There being no schematic and no picture of your assembled device, I can only recommend double checking every component and soldered connection carefully. Pay attention to component values, placement and orientation and the calibration steps described in the manual. It's fairly common to have a kit not work after the first try. See it this way: not only can you now practice your soldering skills, but also your troubleshooting skills.

Comment: Agreed @StarCat. You should get a your multimeter, this schematic, and cup of coffee and go through every single component checking values. You can then power it on and check if each IC is getting the correct supply voltage. Doing these two things will more than likely reveal the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, you should carefully read the capacitance of capacitors! Silly me forgot to check them out before soldering them to the board. In this case, I was using ceramic capacitors and forgot to check the capacitance (those tiny numbers labeled on them in this case, they were too small to actually have the farad sign), and to fix this I used this handy dandy website to enter the values and figure it out:

https://circuitdigest.com/calculators/capacitor-value-code-calculator

For my kit, the capacitors were single digits for the small capacitors and used triple digits for the code. Thankfully everything works now, and thanks to those that took the time to investigate this problem. Remember, CHECK THE VALUES FIRST.

Comment: Count yourself lucky to be able to read the digits, lol. A simple 10X magnifier (with 3 elements, no point skimping there when $30+ will get you something for life) can be very useful to have to hand when trying to read the small writing on components.

Answer (score 0):

AV- seems to connect only to U2 and U4

check V- and check the soldering of U4 and that you installed the right part here.

check also U5.